# Sentry in Spring 1.X simply does not work

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, sentry

We have a spring 1.5.17 app and are trying to simply integrate Sentry.  Because this is an older version of Spring (no, upgrading isn't a possibility), we're following Sentry's `Legacy SDK 1.7` directions [here](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/java/legacy/spring/).  It's quite straightforward.

### Configuration

Here is pom.  We use other spring libraries like logging/actuator/jpa as well but not showing for clarity.  All the same spring version.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.sentry</groupId>
    <artifactId>sentry-spring</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.30</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.17.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Additionally, added `sentry.properties` file under `src/main/resources`.

```
enabled=true
dsn=***
environment=uat
sample.rate=1.0
stacktrace.app.packages=com.pls
stacktrace.hidecommon=false
```

### Application

Created a boilerplate configuration file overwriting the two beans as per sentry docs.

```
@Configuration
public class SentryConfig {

    @Bean
    public HandlerExceptionResolver sentryExceptionResolver() {
        return new io.sentry.spring.SentryExceptionResolver();
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletContextInitializer sentryServletContextInitializer() {
        return new io.sentry.spring.SentryServletContextInitializer();
    }
}
```

Via breakpoints, I've confirmed that these beans are initializing and they are getting the properties from `sentry.properties` correctly.  A [related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62797517/sentry-not-capturing-exceptions-automatically-in-a-spring-boot-application), I found that if I manually make `SentryClient.captureEvent(event)` calls, then events show up in sentry.  **This means that the sentry client is setup correctly and working, but spring isn't actually ever calling `.captureEvent()`.**

To confirm my suspicion, I stepped into the SentryExceptionResolver bean and confirmed the code never hits this breakpoint.

[image]

I've tried to trigger the breakpoint by throwing dummy errors in a `@RestController` ie.

```
@GET
@Path("/test")
public Object throwError(){
  LOGGER.error("ERROR BEING LOGGED");
  throw new RuntimeException("ERROR THROWN");
}
```

While this error is certainly thrown in the console logs, it does NOT trigger the `.capture()` codepath.

### Logging?

The [related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62797517/sentry-not-capturing-exceptions-automatically-in-a-spring-boot-application) mentions something with logging modules, but I don't understand how that's related.  `sentry-spring` dependency is loading all the app needs and the client is being initialized, just never actually called!!

Regardless, I tried adding various logging dependencies (eg. logback as described in this [sentry doc](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/java/legacy/logback/)) to no avail.  What could possibly be missing from my configuration!?!?

In case it matters, we do use spring-boot-starter-logging...

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Note that when I add `sentry-logback` dependency, the app doesn't load.

[image]

Comment: Do you use Spring MVC there? `@GET` and `@Path` look like JAX-RS to me. Nevertheless, Logback integration should work for you. Try the latest sentry-logback from 3.x: https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/java/guides/logback/

Comment: Yes - your'e righ tis is JAX-RS.  Would this explain why the exception handler isn't picked up?  I will try with a proper spring controller.  Regarding logback, I'll try the updated logback repo, but can you help me understand what adding this logback dependency is actually doing?  The linked thread was resolved this way too and I don't understand why some logging framework would affect an error handler getting called...?

Comment: @MaciejWalkowiak - HA you were right, ti was becase I'm using JAX-RS.  Thanks for catching.  This is an inherited project and I didn't really even notice the difference... if you want to poast as answer I'll accept and give you rep

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are using JAX-RS and not Spring MVC. There is no JAX-RS - Sentry integration working out of the box.

To forward exceptions to Sentry you can also use `sentry-logback` integration. You can configure Logback to forward any logger error to Sentry. The drawback of not having Spring integration there too is that errors are not decorated with contextual information from the HTTP request.

Comment: Just curious - do you find it surprising that I cannot use both sentry-spring and sentry-logback (old versions 1.7.30) in the same project?  Seems like sentry-spring steps on the toes of sentry-logback... maybe this is a question for sentry team

Comment: I am from the Sentry team, though I joined to build 3.x version and have not much experience with 1.7.x. AFAIR it should work to use both integrations together, but maybe you want to investigate the source code: https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-java/tree/v1.7.30

Comment: Ok - if this happens in our other services, I will try to make a min example and post a support ticket or something.  Will look at source as well.  Probably going to shelf it but eventually come back.  Thanks again for your help.